# Set GridView elements background color

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a problem with GridView in android. I have read similar posts but this is not the same. The problem is that I set an adapter for my GridView and then I want to do some calculations and decide select one of the elements of GridView, I want to set the background of that TextView to green.
This is the code sample:

```
  GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
  final String[] answerStrings = new String[] {
                TEXT_IN_DRAG_AND_DROP_BOXES,    TEXT_IN_DRAG_AND_DROP_BOXES,
                TEXT_IN_DRAG_AND_DROP_BOXES };
  ArrayAdapter<String> answersViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, answerStrings);

        gv.setAdapter(answersViewAdapter);
        int a = // some process which tells me which child should I change the background of
        gv.getChildAt(a-1).setBackgroundColor(
                        DRAG_AND_DROP_COLOR_BACKGROUND);
```

I receive a NPE, and I know that is because the view is not visible yet. But I do not know how should I solve this problem.

Comment: are you getting  any exception? please mention where did you exactly stuck up?

Comment: You should create custom Adapter, and in `getView()` method apply background

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter and do this calculation in getView to decide the textview to change background color.

Try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> choicesForViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, choices) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                int temp = userAnswers[questionNumber - 1];
                while (temp != 0) {
                    int a = temp % 10;
                    if (position == a - 1) {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(DRAG_AND_DROP_COLOR_BACKGROUND);
                        break;
                    }
                    temp = temp / 10;
                }
                return v;
            };
        };
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> choicesForViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, choices) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
      ViewGroup parent) {
     int temp = userAnswers[questionNumber - 1];
     while (temp != 0) {
      int a = temp % 10;
      if (position == a - 1) {
       super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
         .setBackgroundColor(
           DRAG_AND_DROP_COLOR_BACKGROUND);
      }
      temp = temp / 10;
     }
     return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }